# Is there a GUI for the TLP Power management application?

Tags: software-recommendation, power-management, gui, tlp

I was wondering if somebody already programmed a GUI for the  wonderful TLP power-management application?

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/129#issuecomment-98478154, the main author of TLP has recommended [TLPUI](https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI), which is a GTK GUI written in Python. Do note that this is beta software, so bugs are to be expected.

You first would need to get version 0.9-1 of `tlp` via the [TLP PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/tlp) since the version of `tlp` in the offical repos is only 0.8-1 and the GUI app needs at least version 0.9:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Then, according to the installation instructions at TLPUI's GitHub repo:

1. Download a zip file of the repo at https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI/archive/master.zip
2. Extract the zip file and run `python3 tlpui.py`

Alternatively, you can just use `git` to clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI.git
cd TLPUI
python3 tlpui.py
```

Then do `git pull` or `git fetch` followed by `git merge` periodically to update your local copy of the repo.

Comment: There's a PPA for TLPUI here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/install-tlpui-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html

Comment: The instructions in the repo now says run the gui with `python3 -m tlpui`.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since it still shows up pretty high in search results:

There's also [Slimbook Battery](https://github.com/slimbook/slimbookbattery), a GUI that integrates with TLP and other services to manage power in a more guided way than TLP alone (or TLPUI). It probably gives you less fine-grained control than those other options, but (for me at least) it helps cut through the wall of options.

Install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook
sudo apt install slimbookbattery
```

Once started, Slimbook will also prompt you with other tools you can install to better manage performance/power for your machine.